# Best way to translate while loops to functions for software verification

Tags: functional-programming, software-verification, imperative-programming

I have a verification engine where while loops are translated into functional code, like this:

```
def f() = ... while(c) b ...

def f() = ... fwhile() ...                        
def fwhile() = if(c){ fwhile() }
```

We want for the users to be able to annotate while loops with a decreases construct which says that certain measure decreases at each iteration. This is used to prove termination as follows:

```
while (x > 0) {
 decreases(x)
 x = x - 1
}
```

**The problem is that the checker of the decreases uses the hints given by the preconditions of the functions it is working with**. **We cannot specify that the precondition is the while loop condition since it may be false at the first call**. From my side, I proposed the following translation:

```
def f() = ... if(c) fwhile() else ...        
def fwhile() = b if(c) fwhile() else ...
```

I would like to have some feedback on the correctness of my approach as well as if there are any better options, since still this will require moving in function f a part of the while which should be naturally contained in the fwhile function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend that you translate

```
while(c) b
```

to

```
def myWhile() = if (c) then (b ; myWhile())
myWhile()
```

With this translation, the precondition of `myWhile` is the loop invariant of the original `while` loop.  So, this becomes the question of how to find the loop invariant of a loop.  In general, that requires manual annotation.  If you do a search, you should be able to find a lot of information on finding loop invariants.

Comment: @chi, oops, yes, sorry!  Fixed.  Thank you.

Comment: Isn't `def myWhile() = if (c) then (b ; myWhile())` a bit slicker,  as then you don't have to have the outer conditional. We just do `myWhile()`.

Comment: @AndrejBauer, yes, you're right.  For some reason I had thought that the loop invariant for `remainder()` might be cleaner, but on further reflection I don't think that's the case.  I like your construction better.

Comment: however, with the translation proposed by @AndrejBauer I cannot set c as a precondition of myWhile right?

Comment: @Rodrigo, no -- you couldn't do that with either version.  That's unlikely to be the correct precondition.

Comment: I meant to add it to the already existing preconditions, since the condition is checked before entering the loop and  each time I recall the loop it has to be true then it can be added to the set of preconditions of the function, which is what I need to do verification, otherwise the scheme won't work for the problem i described

Comment: @Rodrigo, sorry, I don't follow what you're trying to say.  The precondition of `myWhile()` depends on both `b` and `c`.  (The same was true for the translation I had in the previous version of this answer, too.)  If you liked the other version better, feel free to use that one instead.